# Reference Request: a "closed under addition" subset of all the nonnegative integers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

I read the equivalent version of the following statement in a chapter about Markov chain in *An Introduction to Stochastic Modeling* by Pinsky and Karlin:

> Suppose $S$ is a subset of all the nonnegative integers and $S$ is closed under addition. Let $p=\gcd S$. Then there exists $N>0$ such that for all $k\geq N$, $kp\in S$.

The book gives no proof. The main discussion is about periodicity of the states of a Markov Chain.

I believe this is quite elementary in number theory but I don't have a proof.

> Would anybody point me to a cited reference in number theory about it?

Comment: what do you mean by $\gcd S$? specially when $S$ can be infinite.

Comment: (I'm going to assume that $S$ is non-empty.) Let $D$ be the set of positive integers that divide each element of $S$. Then $D$ is non-empty because $1\in D$. Fix $b\in S$. If $q\in D$ the $q$ divides $b$, so $q\le b$. It follows that $D$ has at most $b$ elements, and therefore it has a larget element; this is $p$.

Comment: Just found a relevant question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1604366/9464

Answer (score 0):

$S$ has at least $2$ elements (to talk about $\gcd$). Let $S_0 = \{0 < a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_m\}\, (m> 1)$ be the finite subset of $S$ such that $p = \gcd(S_0)$ then there are $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$ 0 < p = x_1 a_1 + x_2 a_2 + \cdots + x_m a_m.$$

Since $a_1, a_2, \cdots , a_m$ are nonnegative integers, $x = \max(x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_m) > 0$ and $\min(x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_m) < x$.

$$ p = \sum_{i=1}^m x_i a_i = x\sum_{i=1}^m a_i - \sum_{i=1}^m(x - x_i)a_i$$

where $x\sum_{i=1}^m a_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^m(x - x_i)a_i$ are both element of $S$.

Let $a_2 = n p$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Consider the nonnegative integer $n_0 = a_2x\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \in S$, $n_0 = (nx\sum_{i=1}^m a_i)p$ is a multiple of $p$.

$$ \forall k \in [0,1,...,n-1], \,\, n_0 + kp = nx\sum_{i=1}^m a_i + k\sum_{i=1}^m x_i a_i = \sum_{i=1}^m (nx - kx_i) a_i \in S.$$

Thus we have the integer $N = nx\sum_{i=1}^m a_i$ such that

$$ \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}_+, \,\, k > N, \,\, kp = n_0 + \lfloor \frac{k - N}{n} \rfloor a_2 + rp \in S,$$

where $r = k - N \mod n$ is an integer between $0$ and $n - 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you happen to know a reference for this statement?